# How do I extract this piece of text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the email from the code below.

```
<div class="col-lg-4" style="border-left:1px solid #d0d0d0;">

    <p>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="/uploads/logos/b75ba9c72de548d665b233d547d92402.jpg" alt="    AJ Navalho">
    </p>
    <h4>    AJ Navalho</h4>
    <p>SEDE/LOJA<br>

    Rua Rómulo de Carvalho, n.º 15
    <br>

    Pendão - 2745-373 Queluz
    <br>

    <br>

    ARMAZÉM
    <br>

    Rua Mário Castelhano, n.º 42
    <br>

    Queluz de Baixo
    <br>

    2745-575 Barcarena
    </p>
    <h3>
        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
         21 435 38 67
    </h3>
    <p>
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> 
        ajnavalho@ajnavalho.pt
    </p>
</div>
```

How do I go about getting the email from the "fa fa-envelope" class?
I'm bad at html so I have no idea what #text is, if that means anything even.

Comment: could you please provide more information on what you need ?

Comment: On the link I provided, there's a small envelope on the right, I'm trying to get the text on the right of the envelope(the email).

Comment: Can't reach the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
r = urllib.urlopen("https://www.oportaldaconstrucao.com/empresa/1964/aj-navalho/").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
letter = soup.find_all("i", class_="fa fa-envelope")[0].next_sibling
print letter
```

Output:

```
ajnavalho@ajnavalho.pt
```

Comment: "module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen'"  

Also, python 3.6

Comment: Yeah I'm using python3

Comment: Try with `import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen("html adrress") as url:
    r = url.read()` Unfortunately I cannot try the python3 code in this pc

Answer (score 0):

Use **BeautifulSoup**

**Demo:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = -->>Your HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("i", class_="fa fa-envelope").parent.text.strip())
```

**Output:**

```
ajnavalho@ajnavalho.pt
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'

Comment: What does `print(soup.find("i", class_="fa fa-envelope"))` print?

Comment: Throws an error >AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'